# How to call the text which is adjacent to a text field?

Tags: website-design, terminology, input-fields, labels

I am having a currency field similar to the below one. What is the UX terminology for the portion which holds the text "**INR**" and non-interactive. I have to decide the SCSS variable name (should be semantic) for that portion. If we name them as *label*, there exists a chance for misconception with the form label element. Kindly assist me.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've generally seen them called "Add-ons".  e.g:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/input-add-ons/